# Parsing each line and column in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script to get all process data.  I'm using the following command

```
ps -eaf -o %cpu,%mem,acflag,acflg,args,blocked,comm,command,cpu,cputime,etime,f,flags,gid,group,inblk,inblock,jobc,ktrace,ktracep,lim,login,logname,lstart,majflt,minflt,msgrcv,msgsnd,ni,nice,nivcsw,nsignals,nsigs,nswap,nvcsw,nwchan,oublk,oublock,p_ru,paddr,pagein,pcpu,pending,pgid,pid,pmem,ppid,pri,pstime,putime,re,rgid,rgroup,rss,ruid,ruser,sess,sig,sigmask,sl,start,stat,state,stime,svgid,svuid,tdev,time,tpgid,tsess,tsiz,tt,tty,ucomm,uid,upr,user,usrpri,utime,vsize,vsz,wchan,wq,wqb,wql,wqr,xstat
```

What I'm trying to do is parse each line and column from this output and I'm kind of lost on where to begin.  Here is the pseudo-code for what I'm wanting to do

```
processes = ps -aef -o ...

for i in processes
  processes[i].ppid  # do some stuff with this column
  processes[i].pid   # do some stuff with this column
  processes[i].stime # do some stuff with this column
```

What is the best way to easily work with the output of this ps command?

Comment: I understand shell is not object oriented, the pseudo-code is that way for readability for what I'm trying to do.  I need to take these fields and put them in another format so I can send it over to another application.  That part is easy, I just need to figure out how to easily loop over/work with the output of ps.

Comment: You can use `awk`, that is tailor made for processing rows and columns

Comment: I ended up using awk, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the output to a loop that reads each column.

```
ps -aef -o ... | while read cpu mem acflag acflg args ...
do
    echo "$cpu"
    echo "$pid"
    ...
done
```

However, this is not going to work well with fields like `args`, since they have embedded whitespace and `read` uses whitespace as its delimiter.